# failed/unauthorized logins attempts via SMTP/IMAP

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-14.04, smtp-auth, abuse

My server host sent me this message:

> 80 failed/unauthorized logins attempts via SMTP/IMAP
>
> We have detected abuse from the IP address `xx.xxx.xx.xx`, which according to a whois lookup is on your network.
>
> Jan 31 07:24:30 server postfix/smtpd[12371]: warning: unknown[xx.xxx.xx.xx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure

Can someone please let me know where to begin looking at for this?

I already installed Fail2Ban and modified my `hosts.allow` which was previously `sendmail:all` and I changed it to `sendmail:localhost`
But both the above methods so far seem ineffective.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Comment: xx.xxx.xx.xx is your IP server address ? or is it an external address banned by your postfix server ?

Comment: @Dom xx.xxx.xx.xx is my IP address. I think somebody is using my server to authenticate to another server.

Comment: Both xx address are the same ? So somebody use your server to test your server ?

Comment: No, it seems more like a hack attempt on a 3rd party server by bombarding too many authentication attempts on that server via my server. It's like my server's smtp is being used somehow by an unknown entity. I changed root password of my server.